# Bom dia, sou iniciante em python e gostaria de saber como posso adicionar as transações que são feitas no array transacoes que está na classe Extrato

Tags: python

```
class Conta:
    def __init__(self,clientes,numero,saldo):
        self.clientes=clientes
        self.numero=numero
        self.saldo=saldo
        self.extrato=Extrato()

    def set_clientes(self,clientes):
        self.clientes=clientes

    def get_clientes(self):
        return self.clientes

    def depositar(self,valor):
        self.saldo+=valor
        self.extrato.transacoes.append(f"Depósito de R${valor:,.2f}")


    def sacar(self,valor):
        if(self.saldo<valor):
            return("Saldo Insuficiente!")
        else:
            self.saldo-=valor
            return("Saque Realizado!")

    def transferencia(self,contadestino,valor):
        if(self.saldo<valor):
            print(f"\n{self.clientes} vocês tentaram realizar uma tranferência de R$ {valor:,.2F} para {contadestino.clientes}\nPorém vocês nao possuem saldo suficiente!")
        else:
            print(f"{self.clientes} solicitaram uma transferencia para {contadestino.clientes}")
            contadestino.depositar(valor)
            self.saldo-=valor
            print(f"Tranferência realizada com sucesso!")
    def gerarsaldo(self):
        print(f"Conta: {self.numero}\n Clientes: {self.clientes}\n Saldo: {self.saldo}")



class Extrato:
    def __init_(self):
        self.transacoes=[]


    def extrato(self,numeroconta):
        self.numeroconta=numeroconta
        print(f"Extrato conta: {self.numeroconta}\n")
        for p in self.transacoes:
            print(self.transacoes[p])

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,nome,cpf):
        self.nome=nome
        self.cpf=cpf
```

Quero adicionar as transações que são feitas na classe Conta, no array "transacoes" que está na classe Extrato

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiro, corrija um pequeno erro no código da classe Extrato. No método **init**, você precisa adicionar um segundo underscore após a palavra init para que o método seja chamado corretamente. O código corrigido ficaria assim:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.transacoes = []
```

Em seguida, na classe Conta, no método depositar e no método transferencia, em vez de acessar diretamente o atributo transacoes da instância da classe Extrato, você deve chamar o método extrato da instância de Extrato e passar a transação como parâmetro. O código fica assim:

```
def depositar(self, valor):
    self.saldo += valor
    self.extrato.extrato(f"Depósito de R${valor:,.2f}")

def transferencia(self, contadestino, valor):
    if self.saldo < valor:
        print(f"\n{self.clientes} vocês tentaram realizar uma tranferência de R$ {valor:,.2f} para {contadestino.clientes}\nPorém vocês nao possuem saldo suficiente!")
    else:
        print(f"{self.clientes} solicitaram uma transferencia para {contadestino.clientes}")
        contadestino.depositar(valor)
        self.saldo -= valor
        self.extrato.extrato(f"Transferência de R${valor:,.2f} para {contadestino.clientes}")
```

Dessa forma, ao chamar o método extrato da instância de Extrato e passar a transação como parâmetro, a transação será adicionada ao array transacoes na classe Extrato espero ter ajudado.

Para mostrar o extrato de cada conta individualmente, você pode adicionar um método na classe Extrato que recebe o número da conta como parâmetro e retorna o extrato específico para essa conta:

```
class Extrato:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transacoes = []

    def adicionar_transacao(self, transacao):
        self.transacoes.append(transacao)

    def extrato_conta(self, numero_conta):
        extrato_conta = []
        for transacao in self.transacoes:
            if transacao["numero_conta"] == numero_conta:
                extrato_conta.append(transacao)
        return extrato_conta
```

O método extrato_conta que recebe o número da conta como parâmetro. Ele percorre todas as transações no array transacoes e verifica se o número da conta da transação corresponde ao número da conta fornecido. Se corresponder, a transação é adicionada a uma lista extrato_conta.

Para adicionar as transações na classe Conta ao array transacoes na classe Extrato, você precisará modificar o método depositar, sacar e transferencia na classe Conta para chamar o método adicionar_transacao da classe Extrato:

```
class Conta:
    def __init__(self, clientes, numero, saldo):
        self.clientes = clientes
        self.numero = numero
        self.saldo = saldo
        self.extrato = Extrato()

    # Restante do código da classe Conta...

    def depositar(self, valor):
        self.saldo += valor
        self.extrato.adicionar_transacao({
            "numero_conta": self.numero,
            "tipo": "Depósito",
            "valor": valor
        })

    def sacar(self, valor):
        if self.saldo < valor:
            return "Saldo Insuficiente!"
        else:
            self.saldo -= valor
            self.extrato.adicionar_transacao({
                "numero_conta": self.numero,
                "tipo": "Saque",
                "valor": valor
            })
            return "Saque Realizado!"

    def transferencia(self, conta_destino, valor):
        if self.saldo < valor:
            return f"{self.clientes} vocês tentaram realizar uma transferência de R$ {valor:,.2f} para {conta_destino.clientes}\nPorém vocês não possuem saldo suficiente!"
        else:
            self.saldo -= valor
            self.extrato.adicionar_transacao({
                "numero_conta": self.numero,
                "tipo": "Transferência - Saída",
                "valor": valor
            })
            conta_destino.depositar(valor)
            conta_destino.extrato.adicionar_transacao({
                "numero_conta": conta_destino.numero,
                "tipo": "Transferência - Entrada",
                "valor": valor
            })
            return "Transferência realizada com sucesso!"
```

Agora, para mostrar o extrato de uma conta específica, você pode chamar o método extrato_conta da classe Extrato, passando o número da conta como argumento:

```
conta1 = Conta("Melo", 123456, 1000)
conta1.depositar(500)
conta1.sacar(200)
conta1.transferencia(conta2, 300)

extrato_conta1 = conta1.extrato.extrato_conta(123456)
for transacao in extrato_conta1:
    print(transacao)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Melo, mas como posso fazer para mostrar o extrato de cada conta individualmente?

Comment: Eu acabei de editar a resposta e adicionei o que solicitou, criando novos métodos para extrato e conta

Comment: Melo, obrigado pela adição, eu alterei meu programa e rodei ele, porém, ele não mostrou resultado nenhum, não mostrou erros também.